# How can I nicely show an absolute value with the "divides" function, |?

Tags: equations

Right now, I am using `\lvert`,`\rvert`, and `\mid` to display

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\lvert x \rvert \mid y$
\end{document}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Interesting issue. You could slight change the height of the `divides` with something like `\newcommand{\Divides}{\mathbin{\big|}}`, and then use `$ \lvert x \rvert  \Divides y $`.

Comment: I think this notation is possibly very confusing.  Why not define an new math operator:  `\DeclareMathOperator{\abs}{abs}` so you would then write `$\abs(x) \mid y$`

Comment: @A.Ellett You make a valid point.  However, it would mean changing throughout the document just to satisfy one occurrence.

Comment: If the numbers are integer, `x\mid y` says exactly the same thing.

Comment: @egreg yay math!  Although I can see how, as a learning student, it could confuse someone (if it were a textbook we were talking about, for example).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Option 1

By making the `\mid` bigger (based on the given comments),

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\abs[1]{\ensuremath{\lvert#1\rvert}}
\newcommand\divides{\ensuremath{\bigm|}}
\begin{document}
$\abs{x} \divides y$
\end{document}
```

### Option 2

By making the font smaller locally, `{\scriptstyle\lvert#1\rvert}`,

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\abs[1]{\ensuremath{{\scriptstyle\lvert#1\rvert}}}
\begin{document}
$\abs{x} \mid y$
\end{document}
```

### Option 3

Rephrasing the mathematical statement,

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=3pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\newcommand\abs[1]{\ensuremath{\lvert#1\rvert}}
\begin{document}
$ y \mod \abs{x} = 0$
\end{document}
```

Comment: The fact that x is made smaller than y makes this look off, IMO

Comment: Instead of renaming `\mid` (first case) I would create a new command `\newcommand{\divides}{\bigm|}`, where `\bigm` automatically provides the spacing you are looking for.

Comment: I will make the \mid bigger.

Comment: If only you removed those useless `\ensuremath` commands…

Comment: @egreg: It can be regarded as a best practice. :-)

Comment: @GarbageCollector *Removing* `\ensuremath` is the best practice.

Answer (score 6):

I think this notation is possibly very confusing. Why not define an new math operator:

```
\DeclareMathOperator{\abs}{abs}
```

so you would then write

```
$\abs(x) \mid y$
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it looks too similar to `\mid`. The best solution I've been able to come up is to reorganize and avoid such constructions (whatever you do, it will look confusing), probably by spelling it out: `... \(\abs{x}\) divides \(y\)...`

Comment: This is immensly better than all the alternatives.

Comment: Come to think about it, what makes `\abs{x}` dividing `y` any different from `x` dividing `y`? (OK, yes, I've had such constructions, but there the `abs{}` meant size/order of a group/...)

Answer (score 0):

I have recently been lecturing on the Sylow theorems and related topics, which means that I am continually needing to say that the size of some group divides or is divisible by something. The solution I have adopted is to denote the size of a finite set by `\#(G)`, not `|G|`.